# How to change halogen bulbs at 18 feet height ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, halogen

How can I change the halogen bulbs above 18 feet high ceiling? How can I change the light bulbs around 20 feet height in tennis court?

Comment: You could use a ladder?

Comment: Maybe this is a case when you should fit a LED, so you don't need to get up there again for a long time.

Comment: Is it a traditional bulb shape or halogen tube shaped bulb?

Answer (score 7):

Some ideas to consider.............................

[image]  [image]   [image]  [image]

Answer (score 4):

[Bulb changer](http://www.toolking.com/bayco-products-lbc-200-light-bulb-changer-for-floodlight?CAWELAID=1410636139&catargetid=1436452153&cagpspn=pla&gclid=CPaA2NzA7LYCFTSVMgodHlMAYA) head with pole and maybe small ladder...